# Meteor - display collection with conditions

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I have a user based Meteor application with a collection representing groups.

A group is something like this:

```
{ name: groupname, members: [memberuseridlist], owner: owneruserid}
```

I have a template for these groups that looks like this:

```
{{#each groups}}
    <li>{{name}}
        -
        <button class="join">+</button>
        <button class="leave">-</button>
        <button class="delete">x</button>
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

But I'd like to ensure that only the relevant buttons are displayed e.g.:

```
 {{#each groups}}
    <li>{{name}}
        -
        {{#unless ismember}}<button class="join">+</button>{{/unless}}
        {{#if ismember}}<button class="leave">-</button>{{/if}}
        {{#if isowner}}<button class="delete">x</button>{{/if}}
    </li>
{{/each}}
```

I have a set of template helper methods but I don't understand how to pass the actual group into the function, so that I can evaluate ismember and isowner for each group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context within `{{#each groups}}` is a group document. So within your helpers you can use `this` to mean a group. Try something like this:

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  ismember: function() {
    return _.contains(this.memberuseridlist, Meteor.userId());
  },
  isowner: function() {
    return this.owner === Meteor.userId();
  }
});
```

If you wish to make these helpers more portable between your templates, see my article on [models](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/models).